# Pull initials from name field adding periods after each initial

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

As the title says, given a column of an arbitrary number of words of arbitrary length, Want a single ArrayFormula to get the first letters of all words in the said column.

I have tried two methods, seen in the sample sheet.

1. Using `SPLIT` and `ARRAYFORMULA` can get it one cell but cannot extend down the column.
2. Using 2 `REGEXEXTRACT`, can get for first 2 initials and extend down

But is it possible to get for an arbitrary number of words for the whole column using `ArrayFormula`?

Is it possible to use `REGEXEXTRACT` to return the first letters of many words?

I would also like to place a ". " after the initials. Example to make Ed Williams into E. W.?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to player0's solution, this might also work

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(len(A:A), regexreplace(substitute(A:A&".", " ", ". "), "[^A-Z.\s]",),)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A, " "), "."))&".", )),,999^99)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A6,"(\w)\S*\s*","$1. ")))
```

- Capture the first letter(`\w`) followed by non `S`pace characters and `s`pace characters
- Replace  everything with just the capture group `\w`(`$1`) and period `.` .
- Convert it to UPPER case, if needed.